# MediaWiki bot users read rights?

Tags: php, mediawiki, bots, mediawiki-api

With the updates to MediaWiki 1.27, there were some authentication changes for the API made (to go alongside authentication changes in general for the Wiki engine). As part of that, I seem to be running into a permissions error in a wiki that's set to not allow reading by anonymous users.

The wiki has `$wgGroupPermissions['*']['read'] = false;` to turn off access for anonymous users.

But using bot created by the new `Special:BotPasswords` page seems to have an issue. I created a bot for an existing `admin` user, which grants "Basic Rights" access to the new bot as a baseline (and "Basic Rights" includes `read` and `writeapi`).

Using the API, I can successfully get a login token and log in (which returns a cookie to set a session), but then using that session cookie to try and do a page query (like, listing `allpages`) results in a `readapidenied` error ("You need read permission to use this module").

Is `readapi` a new permission I have to grant somewhere? Or, is just presenting the session cookie not enough to link the page list request to the login request (how do I carry the authorization from the `login` call forward to other calls?)? Or is this just a bug in the new Bot user infrastructure?

I'm guessing my error is in carrying the session information over to the list query, since if I temporarily put `$wgGroupPermissions['*']['read']` back to `true`, and use the `assert=user` query option, it comes back with an `assertuserfailed` error, indicating a user is not logged in.

Answer (score 1):

In this situation, it turned out to not be related to the `BotPassword` infrastructure, but rather a separate extension:

I also had on this wiki a custom Session Provider (a `ImmutableSessionProviderWithCookie`), which was not properly getting out of the way of the `BotPassword` session provider.

So, if you have a Session Provider that's not supposed to be active for API requests:

- Make sure the Session Provider returns `null` from a `newSessionInfo` call. By default, an `ImmutableSessionProviderWithCookie` implementation will already return `null` from this call because `canChangeUser` returns `false`. If your implementation changes that logic such that in some cases `newSessionInfo` returns non-null, you'll have to override it.
- In your Session Provider's `provideSessionInfo( WebRequest $request )` method, add:

  ```
  // For API requests, ignore
  if ( defined( 'MW_API' )) {
      return null;
  }
  ```

As long as the `newSessionInfo` method and the `provideSessionInfo` method both return `null`, no session cookie will be created for that Session Provider, so it won't interfere with other session cookie providers (like `BotPassword`).

Comment: `ImmutableSessionProviderWithCookie::newSessionInfo` always returns null, and in general it would be strange for an immutable provider to not do that, since the whole point of immutability is that the provider is not in control of whatever credentials are used to authenticate the session.

Comment: True, the `ImmutableSessionProviderWithCookie` by default uses the `SessionProvider::newSessionInfo` logic, which returns null because `ImmutableSessionProviderWithCookie::canChangeUser` is `false`. But in my case, the custom Session Provider is designed to work as an alternate session management, so needs to have `canChangeUser` set to `true` in order to let the user log out (and log back in using a different means). I'll change the wording of my answer to be less specific to my specific case.

Comment: That sounds like a mutable session provider (I guess the documentation is not very clear about the concept of immutability). If you don't have other reasons to bar it from doing API requests (since the web interface itself calls the API for many things, e.g. watch/unwatch, I can't imagine that working well), you can just make sure that the SessionInfo it returns always has lower priority than the one returned by BotPasswordSessionProvider.